# Let's get critical: Jun 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Aviation Stack Exchange](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How is the pitot system drained?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5009/how-is-the-pitot-system-drained)

**Net Score: 20** (Excellent: 20, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How does the ADS-B compact position report NL() function work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/ads-b-compact-position-report-nl-function)

**Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does a dot inside two parenthesis mean on a weather depiction chart?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3894/what-does-a-dot-inside-two-parenthesis-mean-on-a-weather-depiction-chart)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which way should you turn to avoid another aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/which-way-should-you-turn-to-avoid-another-aircraft)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why are delta wings not commonly used in commercial airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/delta-wings-in-commercial-airliner)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the impact of one trailing edge rotary actuator failing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/what-is-the-impact-of-one-trailing-edge-rotary-actuator-failing)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I get the velocity-power curve for a particular aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3626/how-can-i-get-the-velocity-power-curve-for-a-particular-aircraft)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [If turning off electronic gadgets is so important, why are there no detectors used to find them?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/if-turning-off-electronic-gadgets-is-so-important-why-are-there-no-detectors-us)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What does an Air Battle Manager do?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5038/what-does-an-air-battle-manager-do)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [can the wreckages of a hot air balloon and a hang glider be salvaged for a working hang glider?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5023/can-the-wreckages-of-a-hot-air-balloon-and-a-hang-glider-be-salvaged-for-a-worki)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 5)

---